# XamarinEvolve.Backend database required for running backend service

Tags: xamarin

Am looking to run XamarinEvolve.Backend webservice to test and debug the Xamarin service. However the mdb file is not included in the XamarinEvolve \App_Data directory.

Any suggestions where I might get the mdb or SQL code for this ? Thanks

b

Comment: https://github.com/xamarinhq/app-evolve#data-source

Comment: Thanks thats a reference to the MOCK data. Am looking for the MDB database file or SQL code to setup the backend for test purposes. !?

Comment: the backend appears to use EF Model-First, which should build the db for you

Comment: Great thanks. And how would that be done ? Is there a process for database generation from the app or visual studio ?